# Error in setting up a service using lagom

Tags: scala, lagom

I am nearly replicating the shopping crt example of GitHub. I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(41, 32) type mismatch;
 found   : akka.actor.typed.ActorRef[com.rddSpTrMS.api.RDDSpTrView]
 required: akka.actor.typed.ActorRef[com.rddSpTrMS.impl.RDDSpTrState.RDDSpTrSummary]
      .ask(reply => GetRDD(id, reply)
```

to the following lines of code:

```
override def getRDD(id: String): ServiceCall[NotUsed, RDDSpTrView] = ServiceCall { _ =>
    entityRef(id)
      .ask(reply => GetRDD(id, reply)
      .map(summary => convertRDD(id, summary))      )
  }
```

The GetRDD command looks like:

```
  final case class GetRDD(
    cat_id: String,
    replyTo: ActorRef[RDDSpTrSummary]) extends RDDSpTrCommand
```

Any hints would be very helpful. Happy to provide more lines of code.

Comment: Do you have full code pushed on github?

Comment: I do not unfortunately and won't be able to.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the main error above, however for some reason that "reply" inside of the ask method in getRDD method is saying it is "ActorRef[Nothing]" which is causing error at the end of the line because GetRDD is expecting an "ActorRef[RDDSpTrSummary]" instead. Why amy I getting Nothing? Now I am getting a `Error:(41, 12) missing parameter type
      .ask(reply => GetRDD(reply))` error.

Comment: Try to write it as .ask[RDDSpTrSummary](reply => GetRDD(reply))